# Using new Swift regex from xcrun

Tags: swift, regex, xcrun

Why am I not seeing the new Swift regex stuff when I call Swift via `xcrun`? Example:

**~/Desktop/test.swift:**

```
let x = /1/ // totally legal in an iOS or macOS project
```

**At the command line:**

```
% xcrun swift ~/Desktop/test.swift
/Users/mattm1/Desktop/test.swift:1:9: error: '/' is not a prefix unary operator
let x = /1/
        ^
/Users/mattm1/Desktop/test.swift:1:11: error: '/' is not a postfix unary operator
let x = /1/
```

What's gone wrong? My Swift language version seems high enough:

```
% xcrun swift --version
swift-driver version: 1.75.2 Apple Swift version 5.8 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.1 clang-1403.0.22.11.100)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx13.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Xcode 14.3 release notes state that the new regex syntax requires passing `-enable-upcoming-feature BareSlashRegexLiterals` to the compiler to enable the feature: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3-release-notes

Comment: Cool, so I can just say that as part of the `xcrun swift` command! And even without it, I can just use the Regex class initializer directly.

Comment: I’m not sure if you are telling me you can, or asking if you can! I don’t know. I just remember reading about it in the release notes.

Comment: I'm telling you. 